# In Mulesoft ESB how to trigger event after file writing is complete in streaming mode

Tags: streaming, mule, esb

I am trying to create a job in Salesforce.com for downloading a big data set and then streaming it into a file using Mulesoft ESB. While this is working fine, the job usually takes a good amount of time to execute and the file downloading happens after that. I need to figure out a way to communicate to users after the file download is complete. Since in streaming mode the file is downloading in a separate thread of its own, I am not able to figure out when it is complete.
How can this be done?

Comment: The SFDC output is in the form of a stream that I can write to a file. Can I get some help on how to write it into a database instead. That will also solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there were no answers, let me post what I have done as of now.

I used polling service to check status of job on SFDC. If status is completed, in the same process, I start the download process into a CSV file. The polling service also checks for status of download. Once download is complete, in a separate branch of this process, I use groovy to create a dynamic query for creating a table on mysql by getting the "Describe sobject" output from SFDC. I also create a dynamic "load data local infile.." query and run them to load the data into the mysql db.